# Query regarding rethinkdb changefeed

Tags: socket.io, rethinkdb

We are using rethinkdb with changefeed and socket io. And its working fine. In our app for each connection from client(when a user browse to the site) we subscribe the user to a changefeed with the a constant query(like select * from messages). If I open 5 browser instances, 5 times change feed code will get executed.

My question is how the changefeed will work internally. Whether it will listen to 5 changefeed subscriptions to rethnkdb server. Or server will identify unique query and keep on listening to a single changefeed internally for all such client connection and work like a broadcaster.

Thanks
Anup

Answer (score 1):

RethinkDB will deduplicate changefeed messages internally even if you're subscribed to feeds on different queries.  The machine where the write occurs will send a single message to all the machines with subscribed clients, and then those machines will send a message to all the clients that need to see that change.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is:

- create a ConnectionsManager class on each backend server
- the ConnectionHandler registers / un-registers each connection on connect / close
- the ConnectionsManager MUST be the only changeFeed subscriber
- ConnectionsManager will broadcast the changes to all its active connections

This way, it's lighter for the DB as well as the backend.